# 15,000 line listbox save in increments

Tags: vb.net, listbox, save, increment

How could I go about taking 15,000 lines in my listbox and saving them to a different text file in a folder by 100 line increments. So the first 100 lines of my listbox would get saved to folder/List1.txt with 100 lines and so on..

Answer (score 0):

First import the following namespace.

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
```

Collect and convert all the items in the `ListBox`. Use [GetItemText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the string representation of each object as seen on screen.

```
Dim items As List(Of String) = (
    From o As Object
    In Me.ListBox1.Items
    Select Me.ListBox1.GetItemText(o)
).ToList()
```

Define the file path. Do not remove `{0}` as this will be replaced with the "file number".

```
Const path As String = "C:\Users\tantibus\Documents\List{0}.txt"
```

Set loop indices. If you have `15 000` items then `toExclusive` will be set to `150`.

```
Dim fromInclusive As Integer = 0
Dim toExclusive As Integer = CType(Math.Ceiling(items.Count / 100.0R), Integer)
```

Run a [parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539(v=vs.110).aspx) for loop were you skip `(index * 100)` and take `100`. Write the result to a (new) file.

```
Parallel.For(
    fromInclusive,
    toExclusive,
    Sub(index As Integer)
        Dim lines As IEnumerable(Of String) = items.Skip((index * 100)).Take(100)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(
            String.Format(path, (index + 1)),
            String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines),
            False
        )
    End Sub
)
```